# Large directories slow processing

Tags: java, io

We have a java process that does some analysis on files and then writes those files to a directory.   Recently we noticed the process slowing dramatically.   The culprit was the output directory which had grown to over 1 million files.  When we emptied the directory, the speed of the process sped up dramatically.    Why would this be the case?   This is a Windows Server 2012 machine.   No processing is done on the files in the directory (other than writing to the directory after the process is completed).

Comment: What OS is the directory on? Do you do any processing/listing of the directory?

Comment: Mmmm, I would recommend 30,000 as an absolute upper limit for files on a Windows box... maybe create 256 subdirectories 00, 01, 02, 03...fd,fe,ff and spread your files out a bit :-(

Comment: Just the act of creation must go through all the million entries to ensure uniqueness. And the data structure backing the directory isn't optimized for O(1) access.

Comment: To perform a single disk operation on each file for an HDD with 120 IOPS would take 3 hours. Have you considered using an SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a new data structure which sorts your files to subdirectories, or use faster hardware(look into SSDs).  Currently, I believe what is occurring is that when writing a new file you are checking all other files.